# unloading an additional column for one specific value specified in the "WHERE" condition

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

From such a request:

```
WITH t as(
   SELECT a.Id,
      a.Name,
      a.Description,
      b.Title,
      c.Role
   FROM aTable AS a
      LEFT JOIN bTable AS b ON a.Id=b.uuid
      LEFT JOIN cTable AS c ON b.uuid=c.roleId
   WHERE c.role='major' OR c.role='captian'
   GROUP BY a.Id)
SELECT t.Id,
   t.Name,
   t.Description,
   t.Title,
   t.Role,
   d.Email
FROM t
LEFT JOIN dTable AS d ON t.Id=d.Guid
```

I receive mail for both roles (for major and for captain).
Q: How to get mail for captain only?

I attach the result of my script

[image]
and the result I expect

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN` if you only want rows in `bTable` that have a match in `cTable`?

Comment: The GROUP BY is invalid and expected to raise an error. (Unless you're using MySQL in compatibility mode.)

Comment: @jarlh Not necessarily, if a.Id, b.uuid and c.roleId are covered by unique keys, then everything is functionally dependent on a.Id

Comment: @nnichols, you're correct, it could be valid. (But I still don't like code depending on more or less unknown constraints.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `IF()` expression.

```
WITH t as(
   SELECT a.Id,
      a.Name,
      a.Description,
      b.Title,
      c.Role
   FROM aTable AS a
      INNER JOIN bTable AS b ON a.Id=b.uuid
      INNER JOIN cTable AS c ON b.uuid=c.roleId
   WHERE c.role='major' OR c.role='captain'
   GROUP BY a.Id)
SELECT t.Id,
   t.Name,
   t.Description,
   t.Title,
   t.Role,
   IF(c.role = 'captain', d.Email, '') AS Email
FROM t
LEFT JOIN dTable AS d ON t.Id=d.Guid
```